# iOS Core Image: How to use selective color channels and use multiple steps processing

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, core-image

Looking for some Core Image help/direction.

1. What is the best filter to select a color with and darken it? (For instance in Photoshop you can go to Selective Color and choose say Green and then darken or lighten the Green Channel)
2. How can you add multiple filters to a single image? (Say an image needs multiple steps to processing the image and those steps involve different Core Image filters. My specific steps are below.)

If curious, this is what I'm looking to do:

Step A. Start with a color image
[image: original image]

Step B. Convert the hue to green
[image: green hue]

Step C. Convert the image to b/w and adjust the green layer only to darken to black (red or green converts to gray in b/w so darkening the green layer only gets it to black)
[image: final image]

Comment: Use [Core Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I exactly follow what you goal in step C but the following CIKernel will produce an output image like the one you show:

```
kernel vec4 greenToGray (sampler image)
{
  vec4 c = unpremultiply(sample(image, samplerCoord(image)));
  c.rgb  = c.ggg;
  return premultiply(c);
}
```

On iOS you can write this as a CIColorKernel for better perf:

```
kernel vec4 greenToGray (__sample color)
{
  c = unpremultiply(color);
  c.rgb  = c.ggg;
  return premultiply(c);
}
```

Or you can achieve the same result using proper parameters to CIColorMatrix:

```
CIVector* rgbVec = [CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:1 Z:0 W:0];
CIVector* aVec = [CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:0 W:1];
CIVector* biasVec = [CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:0 W:0];
img = [img imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIColorMatrix"
                        params:@{@"inputRedVector" : rgbVec, 
                                 @"inputGreenVector" : rgbVec, 
                                 @"inputBlueVector" : rgbVec, 
                                 @"inputAlphaVector" : aVec, 
                                 @"inputBiasVector" : biasVec}];
```